# How to implement TableView inside CollectionView programatically

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, tableview, collectionview

[Code Snippet](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=33077793375982819225) I want to implement tableView inside CollectionView. It means one collectionView cell can contain one tableView and each tableView will have their own data to render. The direction of collectionView should be horizontal scrollable and It should scroll one page at a time. That page(collectionViewCell) contain tableVie and TableView cell can contain one label and imageView. No of row inside each tableView present within collectionView cell can vary as per data.

Comment: Do you already have some code you could share?

Comment: I have some code but it only implemented collectionView. I haven't implemented the tableView inside collectionView yet and also current implementation is not working for me. so I was hoping that I could get code base / snippet / reference for such problem on StackOverflow

Comment: I have provided the code snippet in form of link